# TCP отправка нескольких файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет

```
path = os.path.join("C:\\Users", os.environ["username"],"cloud")
HOST = '127.0.0.1' # Get local machine name
PORT = 12345 # Reserve a port for your service.
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
bufsize = 1024
tcpCliSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpCliSock.connect(ADDR)
data = ''
f = open(i, 'rb')
print("start while")
while data != b'':
   print(i)
   data = f.read(bufsize)
   tcpCliSock.send(data)
```

Примерно так я отправляю файл на ТСП сервер

```
while True:
    body = tcpCliSock.recv(bufsize).decode()
    print(body)
    if not body:
        print("end")
        break
    bb = bb+body
```

В таком вот цикле я получаю передаваемый файл в переменную
bb.
Возник вопрос, если я хочу передать несколько файлов, например file = ['file.png', 'file.txt']
я попытался сделать цикл в котором отправлял бы файлы,
условно так

```
fir i in file:
  file=open(i,"")
  data = file.read()
  tcpCliSock.send(data)
```

Но после передачи первого файла ТСП сервер закрывает соединение
отрабатывает условие `if not body:`
Что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: А у сервера где цикл с `conn, addr = sock.accept()`? Как-то игрался с сокетами и остался пример передачи файлов: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/socket__tcp__examples/send_recv_file

Comment: к сожалению данный пример не работает. Выдает ошибку ImportError: cannot import name 'send_msg' from 'common'

Comment: Уровнем выше там есть `common.py`. Его тоже нужно скопировать и убрать `import sys` `sys.path.append('..')`, т.к. оно уже не будет нужно

Comment: такая же проблема, первый файл передается а второй нет

Comment: Попробовал -- у меня передается. Покажу в ответе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> такая же проблема, первый файл передается а второй нет

Рабочий код, попробуйте:

**client.py**

```
import socket
from common import send_msg, recv_msg


HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9090


for file_name in ['img.png', 'img2.png']:
    with socket.socket() as sock:
        sock.connect((HOST, PORT))

        with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
            data = f.read()

        print('Sending ({}): {}'.format(len(data), data))
        print()

        send_msg(sock, data)

        print('Receiving')

        response_data = recv_msg(sock)
        print('Response ({}): {}'.format(len(response_data), response_data))

        print('Close\n')
```

**server.py**

```
import socket
from common import send_msg, recv_msg


PORT = 9090


with socket.socket() as sock:
    sock.bind(('', PORT))
    sock.listen()

    print('Server: {}'.format(sock.getsockname()))

    while True:
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        print('Connected:', addr)

        data = recv_msg(conn)
        print('Receiving ({}): {}'.format(len(data), data))

        text = 'Ok! Message size: {}'.format(len(data))
        print('Sending: {}'.format(text))

        rs = bytes(text, 'utf-8')
        send_msg(conn, rs)

        print('Close\n')
```

**common.py**:

```
import struct
from typing import Optional


def send_msg(sock, msg):
    # Prefix each message with a 8-byte length (network byte order)
    msg = struct.pack('>Q', len(msg)) + msg
    sock.sendall(msg)


def recv_msg(sock) -> Optional[bytes]:
    # 8-byte
    payload_size = struct.calcsize(">Q")

    # Read message length and unpack it into an integer
    raw_msg_len = recv_all(sock, payload_size)
    if not raw_msg_len:
        return None

    msg_len = struct.unpack('>Q', raw_msg_len)[0]

    # Read the message data
    return recv_all(sock, msg_len)


def recv_all(sock, n) -> Optional[bytes]:
    # Helper function to recv n bytes or return None if EOF is hit
    data = bytearray()

    while len(data) < n:
        packet = sock.recv(n - len(data))
        if not packet:
            return None

        data += packet

    return bytes(data)
```